# Can I initialize an iterator with null, and if not why?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm trying to initialize an iterator to `NULL`, but it's not working. Can anyone help me?

If a pointer can be initialized with null, why can't we do that for an iterator?

```
vector<int> bob;
vector<int>::iterator it=NULL;
```

I want to initialize an iterator in a class constructor so that at the time of creation of an object of the class, the iterator should be set to `NULL` (default).

Comment: An `iterator` is like a pointer but isn't necessarily a pointer.

Comment: Note: if you let us in on why you are trying too do this, I'm sure someone can give you a working alternative.

Comment: What makes you wonder "why can't we do that for an iterator"? What happens to think otherwise? Maybe make a [mre] to demonstrate and/or explain in detail.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you can't, the more relative question is, *why do you want to?* What are you later-doing with that iterator that is facilitated by first assignment to null ?

Comment: @WhozCraig "that is facilitated by first assigment to null" is what you mean, isn't it?

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and consider explaining what you want to achieve by doing this.

Comment: my question is simple, can I initializing an iterator to NULL, because iterator is  like pointer ,and pointer can be initialized with NULL

Comment: You should not expect that you can initialize an interator with null (except that this is explicitly stated by the docs). The reason for this is because they are not pointers, but iterations.

Comment: I want to initialize a default value for an iterator which is quals to NULL in a class constructor so that while initializing an object of class, iterator should set as NULL(default).

Comment: Are you looking for a default initializer for an iterator?

Comment: yes, but default value should quals NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in general you cannot initialize an iterator with `NULL`. The iterator requirements do not require an iterator to be assignable or initializable from either an integer type or `std::nullptr_t`, the possible types that `NULL` can have.

There is no point in trying to do that. It is simply not needed. But since you have not explained why you would try to do that, I can't really make any further suggestions.

---

Regarding your further questions in the comments: You can *value-initialize* every *forward iterator*:

```
vector<int>::iterator it{}; // value-initialized
```

Since C++14 you are guaranteed that comparing iterators of the same type constructed in this way compare equal.

All container iterators are forward iterators.

Comment: thanks,@walnut the answer I want to know is "I thought an iterator is like a pointer which contains address of an element,if i can initialize a pointer with NULL like (ptr= NULL), why can't I do with iterator like (it = NULL)"

Comment: @N.SANDEEPREDDYsandeep It's like a pointer, but it's not. In the same analogy, a reference is like a pointer to another variable, but it can never be NULL.

Comment: @N.SANDEEPREDDYsandeep a pointer IS an iterator, but an iterator is not guaranteed to BE a pointer. Very frequently, iterators are NOT pointers. In fact, some types of iterators don't even use pointers at all, they use indexes or offsets instead. Iterators are required to ACT LIKE pointers, but not necessarily BE pointers.

Comment: I want to initialize a default value for an iterator which is quals to NULL in a class constructor so that while initializing an object of class, iterator should set as NULL(default) but it not happening.

Comment: Thank You @all ,i got the answer related to my problem but confusion is not yet finished. I need to work out sometime related  to iterators in c++

Comment: Here's an example why this may be useful:  Image you have a set of functions that may store an object in a container, given some key.  If no function stores the object you don't want the value for that key to be set, but if one function does then later functions should update that object.  So you need some representation of an 'empty handle' that you can initialize as _null_ and pass to successive functions in the pipeline to create or update.  You could used `std::optional` but it seems redundant to use `std::optional<iterator>` when an iterator already has a concept of 'maybe a value'.

Comment: I should add, of course each function could each check the container for the (same) key, but in a tight loop a key/value map lookup could be relatively expensive compared to the other work done.

Answer (score 1):

The best equivalent to `NULL` or `null_ptr` for an iterator is the `container::end()` value. It likewise does not point to a valid element of the container. So, instead of testing the predicate `(i == null_ptr)`, test `(i == v.end())`, and initialize as `auto i = v.end();`.

You can't initialize the iterator until after you have a container. But that is not a problem in practice because an iterator makes no sense without a container it refers to.

If you have complicated code that uses iterators, and you want to isolate that code in a function, you will have to pass two iterators to the function: the current or beginning iterator, and the end iterator. This is what the STL does.

Comment: But then you need a`v`. What if you do not have one?