# two singular iterators not forming a valid range with _GLIBCXX_DEBUG

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As I understand, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62266989/4885321) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998624/4885321) it is OK to compare value-initialized iterators even if they're singular. For the singular case, they act as if they were pointing to some virtual empty range.

However, trying to actually use that virtual empty range (with the expectation of it being empty) in a `std::find_if` fires an assertion:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3875:
In function:
    _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = 
    gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Rb_tree_iterator<pair<const char, int> >, 
    debug::multimap<char, int>, bidirectional_iterator_tag>; _Predicate = 
    main()::<lambda(const auto:1&)>]

Error: function requires a valid iterator range [first, last).
```

```cpp
    std::multimap<char, int>::iterator it1{};
    std::multimap<char, int>::iterator it2{};

    (void) (it1==it2); // OK
    std::find_if(it1, it2, [](const auto& el) { return el.second == 8;});
```

According to [24.2.1.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/iterators#iterator.requirements.general-7) algorithms from std should receive a valid range as input. Point [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/iterators#iterator.requirements.general-6) of the same chapter states that

> An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == j. If j is reachable from i, they refer to elements of the same sequence.

In that case it could intuitively be zero steps, though I can see the point for it to be either "no actual range" or "always the same range"; result of `==` suggests the latter option though.

It makes me wonder: what is the rationale behind such decision and what would relaxing it cause, possibly break?

DEMO: https://godbolt.org/z/oPnnaY8jq

Comment: IIUC libstdc++'s debug iterators are not strictly conforming, as indicated by the lack of feature-test macro `__cpp_lib_null_iterators` in debug mode.

Comment: @cpplearner I'm generally leaning towards that but a. I'd to have this confirmed b. how to nolint that away c. should this be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to ask GCC stdlib's maintainers, turns out it's a bug.

https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/libstdc++/2024-March/058461.html

> > What bothers me is whether the empty virtual range limited by two same singular iterators is actually valid or not.

> Yes, it's valid. So the bug is in the __glibcxx_requires_valid_range macro.

Credit goes to Jonathan Wakely.